# Não faz log in depois de publicado no Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-azure

Preciso de ajuda..

Publiquei uma aplicação web, desenvolvida em ASP.NET MVC5 com c#, na plataforma Azure. Esta aplicação tem implementado um sistema de autenticação.

A aplicação funciona bem localmente e também funcionou bem depois de ser publicado, contudo, assim que fiz uma atualização e voltei a republicar, deixou de ser possível fazer log in. Quando carrego no botão log in, depois de preencher o userName e password a aplicação não faz log in e sou reencaminhado novamente para a página de log in, sendo o url da página o seguinte: https//dominiodeexemplo.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F

O mais estranho é que se apagar a app do Azuere e recriar novamente já funciona.

Ou seja, app versão 1, publico e funciona, faço alterações e melhorias (versão 2), publico essas alterações e deixa de funcionar. Apago a app do azure e volto a criar uma nova, publico (versão 2) e volta a funcionar.

Resumindo, de cada vez que altero algo na app tenho do ir ao portal do azure, apagar a app que la está, criar uma nova, e voltar a publicar.

Utilizo o portal do azure com outras aplicações e nunca me aconteceu nada parecido.

Alguém tem ideia de como resolver o assunto ?